# How to display woocommerce product categories on a Page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i'm trying to add woocommerce product categories on a single page, but can't find a solution.

i've tried using these shortcode, but they don't work:

[product_categories number="14"]

or

[product_category category="snowpeak" per_page="12" columns="4" orderby="date" order="desc"]

but i don't get any results. the page is just empty. am i doing something wrong?

is there another way of displaying product categories on a single page? i want to use this page as the homepage. i don't have too much experience with wordpress and don't know how to fix this.

i'm using the latest versions of wordpress and woocommerce. thanks for your help!

Comment: try this one, [product_categories number="12" parent="0"] , is this working?

Comment: And you are double-checked that you *have* defined some product categories?

Comment: Hi @Will the shortcode doesn't show empty categories. Is there a way to show them with shortcode? Thanks!